# Unable to Install a Python Package: Module Not Found Error

Tags: python

I'm facing an issue while trying to install a Python package using pip. I have run the command pip install package-name, but when I try to import the module in my Python script using import package-name, I get a ModuleNotFoundError. I have checked that the package is installed in the correct virtual environment, and I've also verified that the virtual environment is activated. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

I'm encountering a ModuleNotFoundError after installing a Python package using pip. I've confirmed the package is installed, and I'm using the correct virtual environment. What might be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: could you at least give the name of the package ?

Comment: At this point the only thing we can do is guess what you've done. Please [edit] your post to include a shell session where you create a venv, install whatever packages you have problems with, enter said venv and run a python program. Also include the code of said program.